# javascript string manipulation dropping first character

Tags: javascript, string

I am trying to grab all words in a string ignoring any word that starts with "[". However when I do this it works but it ignores the first character?

```
let getText = function(data)
{
  line = "";

  for(let word of data)
  {
    if(word[0] != '[')
    {
      console.log("line: " + line);
      line += line + " ";
    }
  }
  console.log(line);
  return line;
}
```

My output is:

```
Hello this is a test string
word: 
word: Hello 
word: Hello this 
word: Hello this is
word: Hello this is a 
word: Hello this is a test 
word: Hello this is a test string

 ello this is a test string
```

Where the word is the continues string containing just the words I want. The last line is me printing out songLine which is what I return.

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Calling function

```
const fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('files/sample.txt', function(err, data) {
  if(err) throw err;

  let array = data.toString().split("\n");
  let line = array[0];
  //Test for one line
  songLine = getLyrics(songLine.split(" "));
});
```

Comment: You do not have any word starting with `[` in the input?

Comment: Yes I tested it with [ and it works. But I am trying to find out why my final string is dropping the first character.

Comment: You assign the return value to getLyrics.  Is your last line a console.log(getLyrics)?

Comment: Can you make a full example that shows how you're calling it? Use [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to make it executable here.

Comment: @JeffMatthews He's not assigning the return value to `getLyrics`. That's the name of the function being defined.

Comment: I added the calling function to my original post.

Comment: I've executed your code and it's fine.  I mean, returns 'Hello this is a test string'

Comment: What is the difference from .split("\n"); ?

Comment: `.split(/\s+/)` instead of `.split(" ")` will handle `\r`:s. I do not think its really a solution to your problem however.

Comment: @AndersLindén you mean `.split(/\s+/)` :-)

Comment: What does `console.log(songLine.split(" "))` show in the calling code?

Comment: I already have the line though? The problem is when I go through the array given to me from splice it drops the first character...

Comment: @Barmar [ 'Sister', 'Golden', 'Hair', '-America\r' ], this is what is actually read from the file but for now I'm testing it by just saying songLine = "Hello This is a test string";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\r` at the end of the last word is causing `console.log()` to return to the beginning of the line, and then the space that you concatenate after it overwrites the first character.

Trim your words before concatenating them.

```
let getLyrics = function(data)
{
  songLine = "";

  for(let word of data)
  {
    if(word[0] != '[')
    {
      console.log("word: " + songLine);
      songLine += word.trim() + " ";
    }
  }
  console.log(songLine);
  return songLine;
}
```